# ui test xcode, handle datepicker

Tags: swift3, xcode8, ios-ui-automation

i really stuck at this problem
i cant swipe and then select the year at this datepicker, maybe some experienced on automation can give solution [this tupe of datepicker i wabt to handle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cB67.png)

i had code from result of recorded test like below,

```
let datePickersQuery = app.datePickers
    let pickerWheel = datePickersQuery.pickerWheels["2000"]
    pickerWheel.tap()
    pickerWheel.

    let pickerWheel2 = datePickersQuery.pickerWheels["1996"]
    pickerWheel2.tap()
```

but still force close when running the test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You interact with date pickers a little differently and I have never seen recorded tests "get it right". You should use `app.datePickers["Your matcher"].adjust(toPickerWheelValue: <String>)` in order to set a value for a picker.

If you're having trouble with your date picker query, you can specify the index of which picker wheel you want to set by `app.datePickers.element(boundBy: <UInt>)`.

Here's the link to the apple reference doc https://developer.apple.com/reference/xctest/xcuielement/1618672-adjust

Comment: hello, thanks for answering, i got code to fix problem

app.datePickers.pickerWheels["2000"].adjust(toPickerWheelValue: "1987")